# Bind TextBox to Nullable Double?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to bind a Double? to a TextBox, and I am having an issue, because when the user empties the textbox a validation happens.
I thought my application had a validation in some place I couldn't find, so I created a quick app to test.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel() {Value = 3, Value2 = null};
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public double? Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

**The xaml**

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Height="20px">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">Double:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="50px" Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" Height="20px">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0">Double?:</TextBlock>
        <TextBox Width="50px" Text="{Binding Value2}"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

When I run the application the TextBox bound to Value2, is empty, but if I type a value and then delete it, when the TextBox loses focus it shows an error. It only goes away when I type a value.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854860/set-null-to-property-in-mvvm-wpf-when-nothing-is-filled-in-textbox) suggesting to use a string, but he was originally using a double and not **double?**

How can I make this work? Is the only way using a string?

It seems odd to me that binding to **double?** wouldn't allow me setting null values.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type a value that wasn't able to be parsed to a `double`, eg. a word? That 'error' you talked about *could* just be to tell you that you can't enter text into a numerical property.

Comment: I just left the TextBox empty, Eugene suggestion makes sense and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all.

not this:

```
<TextBox Width="50px"
```

but this:

```
<TextBox Width="50"
```

For second: your case should be solved if you do a trick like that:

instead of :

```
 <TextBox Width="50px" Text="{Binding Value2}"></TextBox>
```

do :

```
<TextBox Width="50" Text="{Binding Value2, TargetNullValue=''}"></TextBox>
```

hope that helps

Comment: be aware that input other then double will not go down through your viewmodel - and so your viewmodel still has the "right" old double value

Comment: sensible point. but it's already up to validation techniques :) All user input has to be verified for sure.

Comment: @blindmeis yes, now I have to add some special validators. Thanks!

Comment: @eugene the problem with this situation is that eg. IErrorDataInfo validation will never have a chance to validate the input because an "ABC" input is not send to the viewmodel. but yes you are right user input has to be verified or "forbidden" (decimal input behavior) :)

Comment: @eugene AWESOME!!!  This works great and saved me a bunch of workaround code.  Thanks for this spectacular answer..  'TargetNullValue'  Fantastic !!